# Could not load type 'DataContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I´m using LINQ to SQL classes from a database. When i try to create a new instance it crashes:

```
DataLayerDataContext dataLayerDataContext = new DataLayerDataContext();
```

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'DataLayerDataContext'.]
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +8941051
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.get_ContextType() +107
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you add a reference of DataLayerDataContext your project

Comment: @Prabhavith: I put the DataContext file in a seperate class library and added a reference from that to my project.

Comment: Did u use Using library_name;

Comment: @Prabhavith: Yes, i find it using intellicence without problem, when i debug it, it crash..

Comment: Did you add the assembly reference  (of this class library) in the web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are keeping your `DataContext` separate from your working project, then you need to add the `connection strings` to the database from the `DataContext project` to the working project's config file as well for it to work.

Comment: How can i find the connection string for the DataContext project?

Comment: The connection strings will be stored in `.config` file of your project, eg. if you are using web project then look in `web.config` or `app.config` for windows/console app's

Comment: you mean `app.config` of your working project or the project containing your DataContext classes? Config file must contain the connection string, or must be passed as a parameter to the constructor as suggested by @Laird, how can you generate DataContext classes without a database?

Comment: I copied the connection information from my project to be exact the one in my library class. it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in the connection string to the DataContext constructor as follows:

using(DataLayerDataContext dataLayerDataContext = new DataLayerDataContext("connectionstring"))
{
   Use DataLayerDataContext here.
}

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently after I moved the dbml to a separate class library (one step in many towards extracting the model from the view).  In my case, all of the LinqDataSource's stopped working.

The solution for me was to add the full namespace to the ContextTypeName field in the LinqDataSource.  Find and Replace is your friend.